# Excel Only allow one entry in column?

Tags: excel

I've have a worksheet calls Users and in Column Q rows 10-19 I want the users to be able to select Yes or No from a drop downlist, but only one entry in that column can be set.

Eg:
If they select Yes in Q11, but then select something in Q13, Q13 should be set and Q11 unset.

I've created a named list called YesNo and have applied that to Q10:19 using a List Data Validation., but how do I limit the column to only allow one entry ??

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like what you are after is some sort of "radio button"-behaviour. This might be referred to as "[Option button](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/how-to-create-radio-buttons-in-excel-option-buttons/)" in Excel. Maybe you could elaborate on how you select "Yes" in Q11. Do you manually type "Yes" in that cell, or is done via the form? (Maybe show us a very trimmed down version of the table you are working with, and what other features/tools you use :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Worksheet Event code:

To enter this event-triggered Macro, right click on the sheet tab.
Select "View Code" from the right-click drop-down menu.
Then paste the code below into the window that opens.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim c As Range
    
Set rg = Range("Q10:Q19")

'is the changed cell in the Range to check
If Not Intersect(Target, rg) Is Nothing Then

'Did you enter something in that cell, or just clear it?
    If Len(Target) > 0 Then
    
'Don't trigger the event endlessly
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each c In rg
        
'make sure to not clear the cell we just changed
            If Intersect(c, Target) Is Nothing Then c.ClearContents
        Next c
    End If
End If

're-enable the event method
Application.EnableEvents = True
        
End Sub
```